# How do I add a submit button, and specify that the form should go to "/action_page.php"?

Tags: html

Add a submit button, and specify that the form should go to "/action_page.php".

```
<form ____________="/action_page.php">

Name: <input type="text" name="name">
```

<_________________________>

Comment: Your question seems to be *very* under researched. Have you had trouble finding documentation on how to use forms in HTML?

Comment: Yes. I've been having difficulty in finding how to use forms easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use:

```html
<form method="get" action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

And learn this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Comment: I appreciate the help sorry if it seemed like a stupid question I'm quite new to this.

Comment: @AlexanderTheBored, this is not a problem. We are all be there. :) Could you please to upvote the answer? Someone is downvote it without any reason.

Comment: I actually have but it seems to there is someone who downvoted it.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Send Request">
</form>
```